# Force Jackson serialize LocalDate to Array

Tags: java, json, spring, date, jackson

I'm using spring-boot 2.1.6 and there is an API to accept a form including a date like:

```
@Data
public class MyForm {
    private LocalDate date;
    ...
}

@Controller
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping("...")
    public ResponseEntity<...> post(@RequestBody MyForm myForm) {
        ...
    }
}
```

By default spring MVC accept this JSON format:

```
{
   "date": [2020, 6, 17],
   ...
}
```

So in Front-End, my JavaScript code just submit a form like this, i.e. JS will convert a date to an array.

But when I run spring-boot test, this serialization does not work, with the following code:

```
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void doTest() {
        MyForm form = ...
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/...").
                contentType("application/json").content(mapper.writeValueAsString(form)).andReturn();
        ...
    }
```

This is because Jackson by default serialize LocalDate as:

```
{
    "date": {
        "year":2020,
        "month":"JUNE",
        "monthValue":6,
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

As mentioned here: [LocalDate Serialization: date as array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925899/localdate-serialization-date-as-array) , there are many configurations to force spring-boot serialize data as format `yyyy-MM-dd`. But I don't want to change my JS code. I just want to make my test case work.

How can I configure `ObjectMapper` to force Jackson to serialize LocalDate to Array? I just want to get this:

```
{
   "date": [2020, 6, 17],
   ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

`LocalDate` here is `java.time.LocalDate` but not `org.joda.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: You could try reading the `.content(...)` from a `.json` file. Bit of a workaround instead of writing a custom serializer for a test.

Comment: But in my test case MyForm is generated by a lump of Java code :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register `JavaTimeModule`. Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Example, how to use it:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JsonMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .build();
        mapper.writeValue(System.out, new MyForm());
    }
}

class MyForm {

    private LocalDate value = LocalDate.now();

    public LocalDate getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(LocalDate value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"value":[2020,6,17]}
```

See also:

- [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8)
- [Jackson Serialize Instant to Nanosecond Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345200/jackson-serialize-instant-to-nanosecond-issue/56349458#56349458)
- [Jackson deserialize elasticsearch long as LocalDateTime with Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57098784/jackson-deserialize-elasticsearch-long-as-localdatetime-with-java-8/57102453#57102453)

Answer (score 0):

you can bulid a converter that gets the date value an returns the wanted array.
this will be your entity

```
@JsonSerialize(converter=DateToArray.class)
 private LocalDate date;
```

your converter

```
    @Component
    public class DateToArray extends StdConverter< Date, String[]> {

      @Override
      public String[] convert(Date value) {
          //logic for pushing data into Array and return it
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a custom deserializer for `LocalDate`

```java
class LocalDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDate> {
    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
       // implement;
    }
}
```

And then register it by adding a `Module` bean. From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper):

> Any beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module are automatically registered with the auto-configured Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder and are applied to any ObjectMapper instances that it creates. This provides a global mechanism for contributing custom modules when you add new features to your application.

```java
@Bean
public Module LocalDateDeserializer() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
    return module;
}
```