# How to disable converting the timezone of a ZonedDateTime field to UTC in spring, only for one field and keep it for all other fields?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, jackson

I have a spring boot application where the timezone of a ZonedDateTime field gets converted to UTC when a RESTful API receives a request body that has a ZonedDateTime field. How can I make the application keep the original timezone only for one field and convert it to UTC for all other fields?

I know we can disable this for all fields by adding the below line to the properties file, but in my case I don't want to disable it for all fields, I just want to disable it for one field.

`spring.jackson.deserialization.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE = false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JsonFormat` annotation:

```
@JsonFormat(without = {ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE})
```

Take a look on below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

import static com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat.Feature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE;

public class ZonedJsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();
        JsonMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .build();
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(jsonFile, ZonedPojo.class));
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
class ZonedPojo {
    private ZonedDateTime with;

    @JsonFormat(without = {ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE})
    private ZonedDateTime without;
}
```

Which for below `JSON` payload:

```
{
  "with": "2007-12-03T10:15:30+04:00",
  "without": "2007-12-03T10:15:30+04:00"
}
```

Prints:

```
ZonedPojo(with=2007-12-03T06:15:30Z[UTC], without=2007-12-03T10:15:30+04:00)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me, I added the same exact code to my project and run the code. Here is what I got: 
ZonedPojo(with=2007-12-03T06:15:30Z[UTC], without=2007-12-03T06:15:30Z[UTC])

Comment: @MoA, which version of Jackson and Spring Boot do you use?

Comment: Spring boot version is  '2.4.5'. I'm also using the dependencies  'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux' and "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0" in my project. 
I don't use Jackson directly, it's included with the spring boot, the version is  com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.4

Comment: @MoA, I tested it with `Jackson:2.11.4` and it works properly. Are you sure all imports come from the right libraries and look the same like in my example?

Comment: I had to add the dependency below explicitly to make it work, unfortunately the transitive Jackson dependency that is included in the spring boot didn't work.  
implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.12.4'

Comment: @MoA, I'm glad to hear that. It is always worth to add all [Java 8 modules](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8), [Force Jackson serialize LocalDate to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62423389/force-jackson-serialize-localdate-to-array/62426300#62426300)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this response. Can you please tell me how to achieve the same when using the `Instant` datetime format instead of `ZonedDateTime`?